# When I press save, prettier occured error

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

```
["INFO" - 오후 1:21:30] Formatting file:///Users/DSM20221/jikwan/github/Aliens/DMS/services/admin/src/utils/translate.ts
["INFO" - 오후 1:21:30] Using config file at '/Users/DSM20221/jikwan/github/Aliens/DMS/services/admin/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 오후 1:21:30] Attempted to determine module path from /Users/DSM20221/jikwan/github/Aliens/DMS/services/admin
["ERROR" - 오후 1:21:30] Failed to load module. If you have prettier or plugins referenced in package.json, ensure you have run `npm install`
["ERROR" - 오후 1:21:30] Cannot find module 'prettier' from '/Users/DSM20221/jikwan/github/Aliens/DMS/services/admin'
Error: Cannot find module 'prettier' from '/Users/DSM20221/jikwan/github/Aliens/DMS/services/admin'
    at Function.e.exports [as sync] (/Users/DSM20221/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.12.0/dist/extension.js:1:37299)
    at t.ModuleResolver.findPkg (/Users/DSM20221/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.12.0/dist/extension.js:1:7359)
    at t.ModuleResolver.getPrettierInstance (/Users/DSM20221/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.12.0/dist/extension.js:1:3313)
    at t.default.format (/Users/DSM20221/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.12.0/dist/extension.js:1:13557)
    at t.PrettierEditProvider.provideEdits (/Users/DSM20221/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.12.0/dist/extension.js:1:11429)
    at B.provideDocumentFormattingEdits (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:100:46615)
["ERROR" - 오후 1:21:30] Prettier could not be loaded. See previous logs for more information.
```

When I use save button, prettier occured this error.

How can I fix it?

Our repository is monorepo and we use yarn

I tried reinstall prettier and install eslint-config-prettier and eslint-plugin-prettier but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me.

Comment: Can you add the version of prettier you are using, please ?